# Data duplicates whenever its onclick link is clicked

Tags: firebase, web

So I have a table in html which displays all rentals from my database. The owner name and renter is retrieve from two different queries which is done inside the uery of retrieving data from rental table on database. The The problem is whenever I click the link that enables the function rentalhistory to run, data was added again resulting to duplicate the previous data.  [image]

[image]

```
  var rentalref = db.ref('rental');

        rentalref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        var history = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key; // "ada"

        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(childSnapshot.key);

        childSnapshot.forEach(function(data) {                       
          var pid = data.val().property_id;
          var rid = data.val().renter_id;
          var oid = data.val().owner_id;
          var date = data.val().date_created;

         var userref = db.ref('users/');                      

          userref.orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(rid).once("child_added", function(dataa) {  
          console.log(dataa.val().username);
          var rname = dataa.val().username;

              var userref = db.ref('users/');
              userref.orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(oid).once("child_added", function(dataa2) { 
              var oname = dataa2.val().username;
              $("#rentaltable").append("<tr><td>" +pid+"</td><td>" +oname+"</td><td>" +rname+"</td><td>" +date+"</td></tr>"); 

              });     
            }); 
           });
          });
         });
```

Comment: It seems the problem would be here `$("#rentaltable").append("<tr><td>" +pid+"</td><td>" +oname+"</td><td>" +rname+"</td><td>" +date+"</td></tr>");` because you're appending the rental onto `rentaltable` every time without clearing the previous data. You could remove all entries from `rentaltable ` before adding more or check for existing ones before adding the same one again.

Comment: I just added $("#rentaltable").empty() before my first query and it works!!thank you!